# v-for loop items not immediately updating in Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, v-for

I will explain point by point as it can be a quiet complex.

- I highlight a text with my mouse or trackpad and on mouseup the highlighted text is stored on an array of objects. Each object contains the selected text.
- I wish to loop on that array to be able to display all selection one by one as long as I'm selecting different text.

Basically, I'm storing each selected text to selectionArray. Each selectedText is a string inside an object. So SelectionArray becomes an array of objects like this On the first selection:

```
[
 {selectedText: '...string...'}
]
```

On the second selection the array is updated:

```
[
 {selectedText: '...string...'},
 {selectedText: '...another string...'}
]
```

And so on...
At the end, I loop with v-on on items array which is equal to selectionArray
with:

```
this.items = selectionArray
```

For the moment I'm almost there but something missing as I don't see the modification in live I have to make a useless modification on the HTML (weird) for example to be able to see the result. I'm suspecting the created method but I need help please at least a logic way of investigation. Thx

Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <main class='wrapper'>
    <section class='wrapper-copy'>
      <div class='copy'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis sequi dolorum soluta pariatur asperiores. Recusandae atque nesciunt ipsa velit impedit fugit enim, quia explicabo adipisci sunt earum laudantium illo. Tenetur.
Animi magnam corrupti atque mollitia eaque enim, voluptatum magni laboriosam vel possimus reprehenderit aut doloribus inventore repellat aliquam voluptatem esse ut saepe at iusto qui quibusdam doloremque exercitationem ipsam. Dicta.
In animi nobis accusamus nemo repellat dicta a repellendus provident accusantium fugit voluptas minus laudantium reiciendis cumque, amet porro maiores quisquam? Ullam aut voluptatem delectus cum rerum perferendis vero laudantium!
      </div>

    </section>
    <article class="wrapper-select">
      <div class="select">
        <div id='input'
             class='selected-copy'
             v-for='(item, index) in items' 
             :key='item.index'>
          <div class='index'>{{ index }} </div>
          <p class='selection'> {{ item.selectedText }} </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data () {
      return {
        items: []
      }
    },
    created () {
      var selectionArray = []
      function storeSelection () {
        var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString()
        if (selectedText.length && selectionArray.indexOf(selectedText) === -1) {
          selectionArray[selectionArray.length] = {selectedText}
        }
        console.log(selectionArray)
      }
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', storeSelection)
      this.items = selectionArray
      console.log(this.items)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hard to understand, what you've meant. If you are trying to show selections one by one, why don't you add setTimeout or setInterval? Do you remember `nexttick` feature of vuejs?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan Sorry for the bad explanation and thank you for your time. I will edit my issue now and please tell me if it's better

Comment: @shukshin.ivan done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vue can't detect addition/deletion of array items and object properties. Read the [Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) section of the Vue guide, there it gives you some ideas on how to workaround that problem.

Here's what it says:

Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:

1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue
2. When you modify the length of the array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

To overcome caveat 1, both of the following will accomplish the same as vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue, but will also trigger state updates in the reactivity system:

```
// Vue.set
Vue.set(example1.items, indexOfItem, newValue)

// Array.prototype.splice
example1.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
```

To deal with caveat 2, you can use splice:

```
example1.items.splice(newLength)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. It seems to be the issue you right. The documentation does not explain how and where to implement stuff to overcome caveat. Any advice please?

Comment: Yes it does! It clearly gives a few ways to overcome those caveats. I added a few to my answer.

Comment: Thank you @JakeParis But still don't understand how to implement this. Thank you very much anyway. It a huge step for me :)